# IDE choices for Sun One Webserver 6.1

Tags: java, jsf, sun

Currently I am using Sun Java Studio Creator 2 Update 1. I would like to know what are the other choices.

Creator2U1 is quite OK except the "Theme" feature. I tried to remove the theme and I could not remove it. The reason why I want to remove theme is because of XSS issue. It creates lots of sub-folders.

Thanks

Edit: SOW6.1 requires JSF1.1 Servlet2.3 JSP1.2 (Very old versions...)

Comment: It look like that you're confusing the IDE to be **a part** of JSF/Servlet/JSP or the other way round. This is wrong. You should see the IDE as a standalone tool which really doesn't care about what libraries you're using in your project.

Comment: I think some are part of jsf/servlet. For example, in NetBeans 7, i cannot choose JSF 1.1. May be there is a way to install JSF 1.1 to NetBean 7, but I don't know. Also I don't even see a page to choose servlet version. It just creat as 2.4 (according to web.xml).

Comment: If they are standalone as you said, do you usually install JSF seperately? or It usually comes with IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse EE is a good solution.

Comment: do u know which elicpse version uses jsf1.1 and servlet 2.3?

Comment: just get the latest and set your project facet to use jsf 1.1 and servlet 2.3

Comment: Thanks. I could set to jsf 1.1 and servlet 2.3 in eclipse. But got errors. Now downloading JDK1.4. Gonna play around with eclipse.

Comment: Glad to help. If you find it the answer and comment useful you can always add to the commentors reaitin. This is how it works here.

Comment: "you can always add to the commentors reaitin" << how can I do that?

Comment: by clicking the up arrow left of the comment or up arrow left of the answer (on the top of 0 :) )

Comment: oh.. i can't click it. it says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Netbeans, Eclipse and MyEclipse as other IDEs. MyEclipse is licenced version.